# Grant Execute On with dynamic user subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I execute the grant option on XXX type on ABC user with query-1 successfully

query-1:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON XXX TO ABC WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I fetched current user using query-2 successfully

query-2:

```
select user from dual;
```

Now I want to execute query-1 with the user dynamically.SO I tried to store a user in a variable Say user_name[Means user_name = select user from dual;]

and execute query 1 like ---

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON XXX TO user_name WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I also tried with

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON XXX TO (select user from dual) WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But compilation fails.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way in a `PLSQL` block:

```
declare
     user_name                     varchar2 (100);
     v_sql                         varchar2 (100);
begin
     select 'HR'
       into user_name
       from dual;

     v_sql := 'GRANT EXECUTE ON get_values TO  '||user_name||'  WITH GRANT OPTION';

     execute immediate v_sql;
end;
```